# Build System for Python3 with Sublime3

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, build-system

I've searched hard, but not found exactly what I need. I want to run python3 programs in a terminal from sublime3 using CTRL+B and for the terminal to remain open after the code has run.

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "usr/bin/python3", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

gives `start: missing job name`

```
{
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -u $file;echo;echo Press ENTER to exit; read line\"'"],
"shell": true
}
```

works, but doesn't keep terminal open.

I've seen "/k" somewhere in this connection, but have no idea whare I would put it.

As usual, any help much appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? Your first build system doesn't even make sense, mixing commands from Windows and UNIX.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. I got the first snippet from Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -u $file &&;\"'"],
    "shell": true
}
```

Comment: Sadly not working. Terminal flashes up and instantly disapears with sublime displaying: "(gnome-terminal:2565): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
[Finished in 0.4s]" displays. Any other suggestions?

Comment: {
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -u $file;bash\"'"],
"shell": true
} works, but doesn't keep the interpreter running, just keeps the terminal open.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -i -u $file;bash\"'"],
"shell": true
}
```

did the trick. -i keeps the interpreter open, bash keeps the terminal open. Can't find out what -u does anywhere though...

Comment: if you're curious, the -u flag in python3 specifies unbuffered stdout and stderr